# Cannot find an option to import a release pipeline under Azure DevOps releases

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, azure-releases

Im trying to create an Azure release (not just a release pipeline). I have already a release pipeline in yaml format. How can I import it under the Azure Release section (not under Pipelines but under Release menu option)
I can't find such an option. Does anyone know where is this option?

Comment: I am pretty sure that if you are using yaml pipelines, you should not be using the Release-tab at all. Create the full pipeline (build and/or release) in the Pipelines-tab.

Comment: I am using it and I have already many release pipelines there but the UI and UX is horrible and cannot find release pipelines for each environment easily

Answer (score 0):

You can import release pipeline by using Import release pipeline function but it only support JSON file.

[image]

Comment: I don't see this option. I only see New pipeline

Comment: Hi @pantonis, is there any error message? Please share a screenshot about your situation.

Comment: No error message. just don't t see this option

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have a release pipeline, create a new release pipeline with the "Empty job" template.  You'll then get the option to Import as per Suki Ji-MSFT's answer.